# Lua MVC framework on Heroku

Tags: heroku, lua

I have been developing a Web app in Lua via [Sailor MVC framework](http://sailorproject.org/index.lua) on Windows with MySQL and Apache 2 using mod_lua.so. 
Is there a way to run it successfully on Heroku platform or not?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku doesn't officially support Lua (ref: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#officially-supported-buildpacks). That being said, there appear to be a number of third-party buildpacks that give you a Lua runtime. The first couple that showed up on Google seem somewhat stale. The good news is that you can [create your own buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#creating-a-buildpack) if none of the existing ones work for you.